# Can I use a library compiled with Java 8 in a Java 7 application?

Tags: java, java-8, compatibility

Simple question: If I have an application compiled with Java 7, can I use a library compiled with Java 8 with it? Of course, Java 8 is installed.

Comment: Yes, of course. As long as you then run the project on Java 8.

Comment: If you run a Java 8 JVM, yes; if you run a Java 7 JVM, no (you'll get an `UnsupportedClassVersionError` if you try).

Answer (score 3):

To leave the question not-unanswered, I copied the comment from [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) (emphasizes mine):

> If you run a Java 8 JVM, yes; if you run a Java 7 JVM, no (you'll get an [`UnsupportedClassVersionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html) if you try).